# Testing applications on tablets

Tags: android, testing

I am beginner android developer. I am trying to create a simple game using android-ndk and OpenGL-ES, but the emulator unfortunatelly doesn't support OpenGL. What is more it is a bit slow. So, I am planing buying a tablet with android. Maybe Asus Transformer or Acer Iconia. But I am afraid, will I be able to test my applications on these devices? Aren't there any limitations about that? I read some information on the topic and I suppose that I can install apps signed with the debug key...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to test the applications on any android tablet that has an equal to or higher version of android to your app. For how to do so look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html.